Составить число, все префиксы которого кратны k
Задача Прибыльный стартап
k
друзей организовали стартап по производству укулеле для кошек. На сегодняшний день прибыль составила
n
рублей. Вы, как главный бухгалтер компании, хотите в каждый из ближайших
d
дней приписывать по одной цифре в конец числа, выражающего прибыль. При этом в каждый из дней прибыль должна делиться на
k
.
Формат ввода
В единственной строке входных данных через пробел записаны три числа:
n
,
k
,
d
— изначальная прибыль, количество учредителей компании и количество дней, которое вы собираетесь следить за прибылью
(
1
≤
n
,
k
≤
1
0^
9
,
1
≤
d
≤
1
0^
5
)
. НЕ гарантируется, что
n
делится на
k
.
Формат вывода
Выведите одно целое число
x
— прибыль компании через
d
дней. Первые цифры числа
x
должны совпадать с числом
n
. Все префиксы числа
x
, которые длиннее числа
n
на
1
,
2
,
…
,
d
цифр, должны делиться на
k
. Если возможных ответов несколько, выведите любой из них. Если ответа не существует, выведите
−
1
.
.
Пример 1
Ввод
21 108 1
Вывод
216
Пример 2
Ввод
5 12 4
Вывод
-1
Примечания
В первом тестовом примере всего один день нужно следить за прибылью. Можно дописать цифру
6
в конец числа
21
и получить прибыль, делящуюся на
108
.
Во втором тестовом примере мы в первый же день не можем получить прибыль, делящуюся на
k
, какая бы цифра не была дописана у числу
n
, поэтому ответа не существует.
Не дает пройти на последнем тесте, не понимаю почему (код конечно у меня отстой, ну да ладно)
n,k,d = map(int, input().split())
s = True
for i in range(10):
    nu = n*10 + i
    if nu % k == 0:
        print(nu*10**(d-1))
        s = False
        break
if s:
    print(-1)


И что, не знаете, как выполняется деление с остатком?

Вы написали про помощь, а сами не приложили код, с которым у вас возникли сложности. Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решения задачи и объясните, что не получилось сделать

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Нет. Тема должна быть "решите за мемя" или "напишите мне код", а тут помогите...

@Mbo ок, и какой заголовок тут ставить тогда уж?

@Stanislav Volodarskiy сорри, совсем забыл

@Mbo окей, запомню это

@Akina не в этом дело, он у меня тест почему то не проходит, не понимаю почему(забыл до этого код закрепить)

он у меня тест почему то не проходит Да почти наверняка есть косяк в логике. Либо не учтены какие-то краевые. Вы правда думаете, что кто-то захочет разбираться, какую мысль вы заложили в свой код, без каких либо объяснений и комментариев с вашей стороны? PS. В принципе один косяк виден невооружённым глазом. Для любого k < 10, или для любого n, делящегося нацело на k, ответом является бесконечность.

@Akina насчет мысли я вас понял, учту, и что насчет вашей находки, как можно её исправить? (я не много не понимаю)

Если тесты делаются на Питоне 3.11 или младше, то есть ограничение в 4300 символов при печати целых чисел. Возможно вы в него упираетесь. Думаете как вывести нужный результат без таких длинных целых.

Подумайте вот о чём: если в первый день не подобрали подходящую цифру, то неудача.
А вот если подобрали, то дальше можно особо не стараться - просто добавить нужное количество простых советских ...

я уже подумал и пришел к такому коду                                                                                                               'n,k,d = map(int, input().split())
s = True
for i in range(10):
nu = n10 + i
if nu % k == 0:
print(nu10**(d-1))
s = False
break
if s:
print(-1)'                                                                                                                                                                  но по итогу она выдает ошибку runtime erorr

изменил код в вопросе чтобы вы могли прочитать

12 7 9999  ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300 digits) for integer string conversion. Можно заменить вывод на print(str(nu) + "0"*(d-1))
